# Maven/IntelliJ fails to update Selenium Version to 2.53.0

Tags: java, maven, selenium, intellij-idea

I am trying to update Selenium version from 2.47.1 to 2.53.0 in Maven project. I have updated the required version in pom.xml and expecting that dependencies are resolved automatically (Kept IntelliJ setting for Maven to automatically import dependencies). But I do not see new libraries updated in the project. All classes in the project are started failing as it is not able to find the library. See this image for more details.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxBc0.png)

When I try to add dependency from Maven, it is not showing me latest version 2.53.0. Please suggest.

Comment: Can you share your pom file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Vijendra for your answer. That resolved few errors in my code, but Selenium APIs were still referring to older Selenium Jar 2.47.1 I tried cleaning all local resources and pulled new libraries using Maven, but that did not resolve issue. Finally I deleted the entire local code and set up another code from 'Master' branch in git. Then updated the Selenium Version in pom.xml dependency tag and that pulled all new libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Try Purging your local repository and build again.

```
mvn dependency:purge-local-repository -DactTransitively=false
```

Comment: Thanks Vijendra for this command to purge local repository. I used this and could remove most of the errors from the code. But still there is error for very common method..
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfElement....
giving error that Maven can not resolve the method. I believe that somehow Maven is still referring some old & corrupted libs, which I need to clean up.